Can I stack deck floor frames on top of each other?
I'm designing a new 8'x12' freestanding deck that I'd like to include a 2'x2' inset step into one corner of. It seems like the best approach is to build out two frames - one 8'x10', with the other 8'x2' positioned below it. I'd then build a 6'x 2' box on top of the 8' x 2 to create the 2'x2' inset.
This drawing at least shows what I mean by the positioning of the two decks, but imagine the beams on the shared edge being on top of each other, notched into posts.

Is there any issue with this setup? Is there a better way to create an inset step like this?

For more feedback on your overall design you'd need to share beam and post locations.

Without getting into the nitty-gritty of your design, the answer is yes, as long as you maintain appropriate load paths. This means no impermissible cantilevers and adequate bearing for all members (usually 1-1/2" is enough). This is how most multi-level decks are built.

I believe what you are suggesting is shown in the modified pic

Where as the top joist (Blue line) is sitting on the joist below that is part of the structure for the step. Both are then anchored into a notch in the support post  (represented by the yellow line.
This should be ok, assuming that the post is appropriately sized for the structure. Which could be just a 4x4 if the deck is close to the ground.  An  issue I have, is that the step deck board closest to the deck would not have
support across the entire length up against the deck.  Perhaps better to notch for the deck joist, but bolt the step joist to the posts. So the deck joist is not sitting on the step joist, but the structure has good support throughout.

Good point about the support on that board, I think notching the top one and bolting the bottom makes sense then. Thank you!

That's a step, and will benefit from a handrail to help people visually identify a change in elevation as well as provide support.
Handrail might be free standing, or against the house side.
The yellow vertical post in RMDman's  answer would make a perfect upper newel for a handrail if extended upward, as well as providing structural support.

This answer has nothing to do with the question asked. It should be a comment as an aside.
